# Extract the equal part between strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, equals

I'm searching for a way to extract the common substring of strings in PHP. For example if I have an array like this:

```
$strings[0] = "the 1 o";
$strings[1] = "the 1 e";
$strings[2] = "the 2";
$strings[3] = "the rere";
$strings[4] = "the rere 2";
$strings[5] = "the rere1";
echo sametext($strings);
```

I want a function to return the part that all the strings have in common. In this case it would return "the".

What I have so far is:

```
function find($string){
$same = array();
$let = str_split($string[0]);

for($k=0 ; $k< count($string) ; $k++){
    $let2 = str_split($string[$k]);
    for($i=0 ; $i< count($let) ; $i++){
        if($let[$i]==$let2[$i]){
            $same[$k] = $same[$k].$let[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

finally i want to construct the sentence and if i do

```
$strings[0] = "the black 1 o";
$strings[1] = "the blackr 1 e";
$strings[2] = "the black 1";
$strings[3] = "the black 1";
$strings[4] = "the black 1 2";
$strings[5] = "the black 1";
$all = array();

foreach($strings as $string) {
    foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $value) {
        $all[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
$count = array_count_values($all);
//echo max($count);
$maxs = array_keys($count, max($count));
//echo $maxs;
//arsort($count);
print_r($maxs);
```

the maxs var will contain "the" and "1" but i only want the

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, show us what.

Comment: As it sounds, it would require a lot of comparing (just think about it, for a bit)... Aside from that, will it match words or letters? If so, I would start along using regular expressions to retrieve all words in the string (with preg, the `\b`-assertion might be useful). In all though, it sounds like a quite complicated task...

Answer (score 0):

```
$strings[0] = "the black 51 o";
$strings[1] = "the black 1 e";
$strings[2] = "the black 1";
$strings[3] = "the black 1";
$strings[4] = "the black 1 2";
$strings[5] = "the black 1";
$all = array();

foreach($strings as $string) {
    foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $value) {
        $all[] = $value;
    }
}

//echo '<pre>';
$count = array_count_values($all);
$final='';
$i=0;
$k=0;
//echo $count['the'].'2 1'.count($strings);
foreach($count as $key=>$value) {
    //echo $countw.' '.count($strings).' ';
    if((int)$value == count($strings) && $i==$k ){
        if($i==0){
            $final = $final.$key;
            $i++;
        }
        else{
            $final = $final.' '.$key;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $k++;
}
echo $final;
```